# How to manage a fully separate context with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a javascript test framework based on nodejs. My server reads javacript files, instruments them, then executes them in its own context.

It (very) basically looks like this:

```
const file = process.argv[2];

require('fs').readFile(
    file,
    'utf-8',
    (error, data) => {
        eval(data);
    }
);
```

This is all working fine but I do not like mixing my server context with a test context. **How can nodejs execute javascript code in a totally separate context?**

Ideally, it would be something like this:

```
other_context.eval(data);
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: To protect your whole server from this test code, you would really need a VM so you could run a new nodejs process in the VM.  The new process protects your main nodejs process from the test code.  The VM protects the rest of your server from what the test code might do.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks for your inputs. Actually, my *server* just watches local files. So I'm not worried right now about security. I'm trying a lightweight solution. But I'll certainly consider VM if it goes online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this.  The easiest thing that you could try right now is to replace the file read with [`child_process#fork()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options).

This means you are running in a totally separate process which is good and that you don't need `eval()` which is also **very** good.

Essentially:

```js
const {
  fork
} = require('child_process');

const child = fork(file);
child.on("message", m => console.log(m));
```

---

The main thing is to get the code that you are testing out of the server.  I just think terrible things can happen if you leave it that way.

Another option that is too broad to cover is to leverage Docker.  That way, the code that gets executed is not only in another process, it's (and this is painting really broadly) practically on another computer.

Comment: `fork` provides me perfect isolation, but how can I easily interface my server to its child process? My server runs watchers on directories and performs *live* instrumentation upon change.

Comment: Well it seems all doable with `child.on`/`child.send` and `process.on`/`process.send`. Let me try this!

Comment: Solution with fork worked for me. In the end, I chose [safe-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval) for flexibility. If you want to try my test framework: https://github.com/RaphaelSaban/jfest

Answer (score 3):

[`isolated-vm`](https://github.com/laverdet/isolated-vm) might fit the bill for you.

> isolated-vm is a library for nodejs which gives you access to v8's Isolate interface. This allows you to create JavaScript environments which are completely isolated from each other. You might find this module useful if you need to run some untrusted code in a secure way. You may also find this module useful if you need to run some JavaScript simultaneously in multiple threads. You may find this project very useful if you need to do both at the same time!

Comment: Sounds great! Would you mind give me a snippet with `isolated-vm` to show what it would look like?